# QR Factorization with a zero eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

If my (square) matrix $A$ has zero as a single, simple, eigenvalue, is the associated QR factorization still unique?  The uniqueness results I've seen seem to only apply in the case that $A$ has full rank, hence no zero eigenvalue.

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} r_{11} & r_{12} \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} r_{11} & r_{12} \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.